# Apple's Instruments Sample List

Tags: profiling, instruments, xcode-instruments

I am trying to understand Apple's Instruments GUI right now, in particular the **Sample List** view.

Here I am monitoring L2 cache misses, and in the **Tree View** is quite straightforward how to oder columns and see who is the culprit:

[image: tree]

However, in the **Sample List**, I see **negative numbers** and one thing that I don't understand: there seems to be **no order**:

[image: top of ordered list]

The top of the list starts at -21M, it "grows" (by absolute value?) until -60M and then goes to 60M (positive):

[image: mid list]

So my question is: *how can I use the Sample List* in Apple's Instruments? What is its purpose, and what am I missing in "ordering" samples?

Answer (score 0):

You can order samples by clicking on a column heading. For example, clicking on the Timestamp column will sort the samples by the time Instruments took the sample.

I find that the Sample List is hard to use because Instruments takes too many samples. The Sample List is more useful for something like the Allocations instrument where there can be large differences in each sample. In the allocations list, you can sort by allocation size and examine the largest memory allocations. The Sample list is less useful for cache misses and instruments where there aren't big differences in the individual samples.